# Net::CUPS->getDestinations() output

Tags: perl, printing, cups

I am trying to use Net::CUPS->getDestinations() to get a list of printer names that are configured in CUPS.

- Ubuntu Server 14.04.3
- CUPS 1.7.2
- Perl 5.18.2
- Net::CUPS 0.61

A short demo progam like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::CUPS;
my $cups = Net::CUPS->new();
my @prts = $cups->getDestinations();
foreach my $printer (@prts) {
  print "$printer\n";
}
exit;
```

has an output of

```
Net::CUPS::Destination=SCALAR(0x1e13bb0)
Net::CUPS::Destination=SCALAR(0x1e13bf8)
Net::CUPS::Destination=SCALAR(0x1e13c88)
Net::CUPS::Destination=SCALAR(0x1e13d18)
Net::CUPS::Destination=SCALAR(0x1e13d00)
Net::CUPS::Destination=SCALAR(0x1e4c9c8)
```

I'm expecting printer names, or something I can pass to another function to get the printer name. 
It seems I am interpreting this part of the documentation wrong.

```
getDestinations
    my @printers = $cups->getDestinations();
 This method will return an array of destinations currently configured  on the cups server.
```

Does anyone know how to get a list of printers configured in CUPS using the Net::CUPS module?

Comment: I believe from the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::CUPS::Destination#getName)  `$printer->getName();` will work for you in your for-loop.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. That was the answer. I didn't realise that getDestinations() was returning an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Arunesh Singh, changing the foreach loop a little is the solution. 
I now realise that getDestinations() is returning an array of objects.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::CUPS;
my $cups = Net::CUPS->new();
my @prts = $cups->getDestinations();
foreach my $printer (@prts) {
  my $name = $printer->getName();
  print "$name\n";
}
exit;
```